# How to Disallow Particular Path in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I want to disallow `/path` but also wanna allow `/path/another-path` in `robots.txt`. I already tried:

```
Disallow: /path
```

Or:

```
Disallow: /path$
```

But doesn't work, I mean it blocked `/path/another-path` too. Is it possible to do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Allow`. But note that it's not part of the original "specification", however, some search engines support it.

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /path/another-path
Disallow: /path/
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Allow_directive, for example.